# redirecting to specified page, after login - keycloak

Tags: authentication, url, redirect, keycloak, store

I'm clicking on url which is redirecting me to some page on my website. Everything works fine until user is not logged in. How to redirect someone to url which I clicked after login? is there way to store this url or something?

I've tried so hard and get so far but in the end it doesnt really matters

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.redirectUri` to set the redirect URL. Make sure the URL is also set in `Valid redirect URIs` of client.

```
const Login = (onAuthenticatedCallback) => {
    keycloakInstance
        .init({
            ...
        })
        .then(function (authenticated) {
            if (authenticated) {
                ...

                keycloakInstance.redirectUri = window.location.origin + "/HomePage"
            } else {
                alert("non authenticated")
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(`keycloak init exception: ${e}`);
        });
};
```